# Recurrence equation and special functions

Tags: special-functions, recurrence-relations

Can someone give me a proof or a hint on why the recurrence equation:
$$g(k+2)=k*g(k+1)-g(k)$$
has the solution:
$$g(k)=c_1 {_0\tilde F_1}(;k;-1)+c_2 Y_{k-1}(2)$$
where ${_0\tilde F_1}(;a;x)$ is the regularized hypergeometric function and $Y_{k-1}(2)$ is the Bessel function of the second kind?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recurrence equation is an instance of the recurrence equation, satisfied by Bessel functions:
$$
      x J_{\nu-1}(x) + x J_{\nu+1}(x) = 2\nu J_{\nu}(x), \quad
      x Y_{\nu-1}(x) + x Y_{\nu+1}(x) = 2\nu Y_{\nu}(x)
$$
for $x=2$. Moreover, [Casoratian](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Casoratian.html) of $J_{k-1}(2)$ and $Y_{k-1}(2)$ is non-zero for all $k$
$$
     C(J_{k-1}(2), Y_{k-1}(2)) = J_{k-1}(2) Y_k(2) - Y_{k-1}(2) J_k(2) \stackrel{\text{Wronskian}}{=} \left.-\frac{2}{\pi x}\right|_{x=2} = -\frac{1}{\pi} \not= 0
$$
therefore $J_{k-1}(2)$ and $Y_{k-1}(2)$ are linearly independent solutions of the recurrence equation, and hence $g(k) = c_1 J_{k-1}(2) + c_2 Y_{k-1}(2)$ is the fundamental system.

Incidentally:
$$
   {}_0 \tilde{F}_1\left(;k;-x^2\right) = x^{k-1} J_{k-1}(2x)
$$